# getting null value when using getter function in another java class

Tags: android, getter-setter

I have a MainActivity in which i am getting data from server and i want to set the data using setters and getter. I am using setter function to set the value in Mainactivity. the data is accessed properly if i use it MainActivity. i have another java class AlarmReceiver. I want to access the value which is set in the MainActiviy. But i am not getting any value here in Another class.

Here is my MainActivity

```
 JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(strServerResponse);
 JSONObject jsonObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
 String DataStatus = jsonObj.getString("status");

 System.out.println(DataStatus);
 if (DataStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
        JSONArray arr1 = new JSONArray(strServerResponse);
        JSONObject jsonObj1 = arr.getJSONObject(0);

        pojo = new Pojo();
        empid = jsonObj1.optString("empid");
        pojo.setId(empid);
```

And this is AlarmReceiver

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    gps = new GPSTracker(context);


    Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    gpxfile = new File(root, "mydata.csv");

    startService();
}

private void startService() {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMMM:yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
    strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());


    pojo=new Pojo();
    String id=pojo.getId();
```

And these are setter getters

```
  public class Pojo {
public static String empid11;
public void setId(String empid) {
    this.empid11 = empid;
    Log.e("empidd setter",""+empid);
}

public String getId() {
    Log.e("empidd getter",""+empid11);

    return empid11;
}
}
```

But I am getting null value in the AlarmReceiver. Ho to get this value?

Comment: You are doing pojo=new Pojo(); in startService() which creates new instance of POJO class. you have to pass the instance in which you set the values to AlarmReceiver to get it working.

Comment: if i use pojo=new Pojo();  in onReceive() then also it does not work

Comment: You have to pass MainActivity pojo instance in which you have added empid to AlarmReceiver then only it will work else you will always get NPE

Answer (score 0):

Your pojo is a new Pojo. You need to pass the same object to which the Id was saved.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pojo pojo =new Pojo(); //global declaration
```

setting value to pojo

```
   empid = jsonObj1.optString("empid");
        pojo.setId(empid);
```

and in your `startService()` method,remove new Instance of Pojo,i.e remove `new Pojo();`

```
private void startService() {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMMM:yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
    strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    String id=pojo.getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your getter setter like this :

```
public void setMethod (String string)
{
     this.string= string;
}

// getting the ArrayList value 
public static String getMethod() 
{
     return string;
}
```

You can use your getmethod name by using yourclassname.getMethod().

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure how and when you AlarmReceiver is getting executed. So for a solution you can make the pojo instance in MainActivity public static i.e.

```
public static Pojo pojo = null;
```

Initialize this instance as you are currently doing :-

```
pojo = new Pojo();
empid = jsonObj1.optString("empid");
pojo.setId(empid);
```

Inside your AlarmReceiver startService() method you can use this as

```
if (MainActivity.pojo != null){
    String id=pojo.getId();
}
```

Remove all local instances/variables of POJO class inside AlarmReceiver class.

**Though this approach is not advisable.**

Answer (score 0):

To find a proper solution, I suggest you to take a closer look on the differences between an object, instance and classes in Java.

some recommended links are:

[Source1](https://alfredjava.wordpress.com/2008/07/08/class-vs-object-vs-instance/)

[Source2](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr96/cs333/java/tutorial/java/anatomy/static.html)

Additionally you can check out *static classes* and *singletons*.